# Do initial parameters in this global optimization problem matter?

Tags: optimization, global-optimization

Let's say I have some data to adjust to this model:

$$V=V_0 +K_1(\cos (\omega_1 +f_1)+e_1\cos(\omega_1)) + K_2(\cos (\omega_2 +f_2)+e_2\cos(\omega_2)), $$

with $V_0$, $K_1$, $K_2$, $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, $e_1$, $e_2$, $T_1$, $T_2$ parameters of the problem, $f_1(f_2)$ depends on $T_1(T_2)$ and $e_1(e_2)$. Note the model is just a sum of two sinusoidal waves.

I was trying to fit these parameters using the dual-annealing function in [Python](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html), which doesn't require no initial parameters but just bounds to each one of the parameters. That made me think, does it mean that in a global minimum problem like this the solution doesn't depend on the initial guesses of the parameters? And if so, does it affect the accuracy of the solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Simulated annealing methods are stochastic methods inspired in the metal annealing with cooling process. It can be considered a stochastic gradient method and it's application doesn't depends on the initial point but depends on the search region size. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) short introduction.